# It is possible to override/remove page Content Security Policy through the external script?

Tags: javascript, html, security, http-headers, content-security-policy

I'm write an external script for a single web page and i need to make one `POST JSON` request to another resource through this script.

However, when i do, it throws CSP error: `"Refused to connect to <URL> because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self'"`.

I looked into the web page  and see meta tag which contain a Content-Security-Policy with CSP content. However, i tried manually add my `<URL>` to CSP `connect-src` content, but it is still not working.

**Questions:**

- can i change CSP through the external script? How?
- maybe any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying the setting that needs to be changed:

> it violates the following `Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self'"`

So you need to set the 'connect-src' directive to something other than 'self', which might have been set by default.

You said you tried to add the URL that you're trying to connect to. That is not quite right - you need to add just the host part, rather than any of the path.

So the connect-src part of the CSP header should look like:

```
connect-src 'self' https://*.example.com
```

If you update your question with what you tried, if it still isn't working, the exact error could be diagnosed.

Comment: It is not a my resource and i can't control it CSP.

>Meta tags don't set CSP....it is only headers.
Then for what purpose meta tag for CSP is exists? https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp/#the_meta_tag https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy#Multiple_content_security_policies

Comment: I did not know that they could be set in meta tags - I've removed that wrongness from my answer.

Comment: It is all right! All our life we learn something new.  

And looks like any change to CSP meta tags doesn't working because browser uses only the first version of CSP meta tag, which was sended by server. Which makes sense, because we can change these tags through JS, and that would be a huge security hole.